# Meaning of "standard deviation noises of wavelet coefficients"

Tags: wavelet, acoustics

I am currently working on a research project based on the paper titled [A deep learning approach for anomaly detection based on SAE and LSTM in mechanical equipment](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00170-019-03557-w). The paper uses data in the acoustic domain and processes it with techniques such as FFT and WPD to extract a total of 11 features per recording channel.

In their case, they use a 3 axis accelerometer working at a sampling frequency of 4096Hz, recording the acceleration of a rotating mechanical equipment. Every axis is processed separately and the results are then combined in groups of similar features.

In the section describing what features are to be extracted one particular sentence says that

> Features 7–18 denote the standard deviation noises of wavelet coefficients at levels 1–4 in direction X, Y, and Z.

I have attempted to ask my supervisor about this as well as my digital signal processing teacher about it, but neither of them has been able to give me an explanation as for the meaning of "standard deviation noises", neither has any internet search provided significant results.

I have thus interpreted this as "standard deviation of the WPD details at levels 1-4", and have as such computed the said features by directly computing the standard deviation of the WPD levels `D`, `AD`, `AAD` and `AAAD`.

I am however concerned that my interpretation might have been flawed, and would therefore like to know if that is the correct interpretation, or whether I am completely wrong.

So, is my interpretation correct, or is it completely off? In which case, what would be the correct interpretation?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  I have tried to contact the [first author](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Zhe-Li-6) of that paper to see if they have a response.

Comment: That's very kind of you, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Your interpretation is natural. What bothers me is that other features are "percentages of energy corresponding to the details at levels 1–4 and three directions". As wavelet coeffcients often have zero-mean, the standard deviation of coefficients and their energy are very related

Comment: @LaurentDuval I'm not yet too familiar with these relationships, but I'll keep it in mind, thank you for your input. My only concern with my interpretation is that it doesn't make use of the fact the WPD divides both the approximation and the detail into further levels, and instead uses components a DWT would have computed anyway, from my understanding, so I don't see the advantage of the WPD here.

Comment: @LaurentDuval I actually did some more research and you are right, these two values seem very tightly coupled.

Comment: Indeed, if I understand well, up to normalization or scaling

Comment: @LaurentDuval I believe it won't be too much of a problem in my case, as from my understanding the energy percentages are relative to a particular sample and values are normalized relative to the sample itself, whereas the standard deviation values are normalized relative to the entire dataset, and although values from one sample have kept their relative ratio, they still provide information compared to the dataset itself. That's how I have implemented it at least.